# What does "all", "oss", "all-oss" mean in the Docker image tag of timescale/timescaledb-ha?

Tags: timescaledb

TimescaleDB Docker image has many tags. [Here](https://hub.docker.com/r/timescale/timescaledb-ha/tags?page=1&name=pg15.3-ts2.10.3-) are some of them:

- pg15.3-ts2.10.3-all
- pg15.3-ts2.10.3-all-oss
- pg15.3-ts2.10.3-oss

[image]

I can understand

- `pg15.3` means Postgres 15.3
- `ts2.10.3` means TimescaleDB 2.10.3

For the rest of `all`, `oss`, `all-oss`, I know [TimescaleDB has two licenses](https://www.timescale.com/legal/licenses):

- TimescaleDB Open Source is made available under the Apache 2.0 License
- TimescaleDB Community is made available under the Timescale License ("TSL")

If `oss` is for TimescaleDB Open Source, `all` is for TimescaleDB Community, then what is `all-oss`? I kind of feeling `all` means something else. And does this `oss` really refer to Open Source license?

Could someone help clarify? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-all` means that all the supported PostgreSQL versions are included, so `pg15-all` also includes pg12-14 as well as pg15.

The older versions of pg are included so that people can run `pg_upgrade` to upgrade their databases, as `pg_upgrade` requires both the old and the new versions of the pg binaries.

`-oss` is the Apache licensed version, and the images without `-oss` are the community licensed version.